# Wmic error handling in Batch script

Tags: variables, batch-file, uninstallation, wmic

I am writing a Batch to uninstall a sofware from a domain envirement but stuck.
The problem is that i need a return value to a variable of the wmic uninstall call but get nothing if its an RPC error,not even an errorlevel but i need it to separate the good and bad ones in a logfile.

```
setlocal enableextensions EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
set v=

echo Nem voltak elerhetok > nemelerheto.txt
echo Hibakk > log.txt
echo. >>log.txt
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%v in (runtime2k3.txt) do (
    IF Not !volt!==%%v (
        echo %%v >> log.txt
        echo %%v
        for /f %%p in ('ping -n 1 %%v ^| find /c "(0%% loss)"') do (
            if %%p==1 (
            echo elerheto
            echo elerheto >> log.txt
            wmic /output:wmic.txt /user:****** /password:"******" /node:%%v      product where name^="Microsoft Office Access 2003 Runtime" call uninstall  



            )
            if %%p==0 (
                echo %%v >> nemelerheto.txt
                echo nemelerheto >> log.txt
            )
        )   
    set array[!i!]=%%v
    set volt=%%v

    set /a i=!i!+1


    )
    echo. >> log.txt 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to produce something in `WMIC` in the way you are using it.
You only pass a global switches  e.g. test :

```
wmic /node:no_such_server
```

To make wmic to do something use some of the commands/aliases. -> http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html

to check the sever try something harmless and short e.g `wmic timezone get Bias`